# Can't get ModelForm ChoiceField return as string - Cannot assign "'5'": "Reclamacoes.uf" must be a "Estados" instance

Tags: python, mysql, django, modelform

This form gets entries from models Estados, Cidades, Categorias and Status from the database, to be displayed in ChoiceFields. The other fields are CharFields, EmailFields and a PhoneNumberField (from [this lib](https://github.com/stefanfoulis/django-phonenumber-field)).

After pressing the submit button with proper data, I get the following error: "Cannot assign "'5'": "Reclamacoes.uf" must be a "Estados" instance." Tried several different widgets and form elements to try and get this input as string (including forms.Select), but they don't fulfill the purpose I'm looking for.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField

class Estados(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(("nome"), max_length=50)
    unidade = models.CharField(("unidade"), max_length=2)
    disponibilidade = models.BooleanField(("disponibilidade"), default=False)

class Cidades(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(("nome"), max_length=50)
    uf = models.ForeignKey("Estados", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    disponibilidade = models.BooleanField(("disponibilidade"), default=False)

class Categorias(models.Model):
    tipo = models.CharField(("tipo"), max_length=50)
    disponibilidade = models.BooleanField(("disponibilidade"), default=False)
    nome = models.CharField(("nome"), max_length=50)

class Status(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(("status"), max_length=50)

class Reclamacoes(models.Model):
    uf = models.ForeignKey("Estados", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cidade = models.ForeignKey("Cidades", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    categoria = models.ForeignKey("Categorias", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    autor = models.CharField(("autor"), max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(("email"), max_length=254)
    telefone = PhoneNumberField(null=False, blank=False, unique=False)
    reclamacao = models.CharField(("reclamacao"), max_length=50000)
    status = models.ForeignKey("Status", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.db.models import fields
from phonenumber_field.formfields import PhoneNumberField
from .models import Estados, Cidades, Categorias, Status, Reclamacoes
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError


class FormReclamacao(forms.ModelForm):
    
    uf = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(item.id, item.nome) for item in Estados.objects.filter(disponibilidade=1).order_by('unidade')])
    cidade = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(item.id, item.nome) for item in Cidades.objects.filter(disponibilidade=1).order_by('nome')])
    categoria = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(item.id, item.nome) for item in Categorias.objects.filter(disponibilidade=1)])
    status = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(item.id, item.status) for item in Status.objects.all()])
    class Meta:
        model = Reclamacoes
        fields = ("__all__")
```

views.py

```
def reclamacoes(request):
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_rec = FormReclamacao(request.POST)

        if form_rec.is_valid():
            r = form_rec.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/cad')
            
    else:
        form_rec = FormReclamacao()

    return render(request, 'reclamacoes.html', {'form':form_rec})
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says that you are trying to either assign a string or integer 5 as a foreign key in the `Reclamacoes` model, which will not work. You cannot assign a string or integer to a foreign key field. It has to be an instance of the model that you are referring to.

What you may need to do is extract the id of the `Estados` model, which in this case is `5`.

So in your `views.py` in the `if form_rec.is_valid():` block alter the save method:

```
r = form_rec.save(commit=False)

estado_id = form.cleaned_data["uf"]

# make sure that estado_id is an int and not a string

estado = Estado.objects.get(id=estado_id)
r.uf = estado

#... do the same for all foreign keys ...

r.save()
```

Comment: I've tried this solution before, but it didn't work either, returning the same error

Comment: After this line `estado = Estado.objects.get(id=estado_id)` add a print statement below it. Like `print(estado)` and `print(type(estado))`. Then check what is output in the console.

Comment: I've rewritten the code from scratch, now using a different approach. jQuery + AJAX to fulfill the purposes I was looking for. But thanks dude, your answer has put me in the right path!